# Do the images located on my domain benefit me when I post them as images on third-party websites with "src" pointing to my domain?

Tags: url, images, forum

For instance, if `example.com` is my domain and the following is posted on a third-party website, forum, etc:

```
<img src="example.com/images/img1.jpg" />
```

Does this benefit `example.com`?

Comment: Is this from a purely SEO perspective? (Being picky perhaps, but your _example_ won't even get to _your domain_.)

Comment: @MrWhite purely SEO

Comment: @アレックス Hang on, are you the OP?

Comment: @アレックス Are you the person who posted this question?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister yes. What of it?

Comment: @MrWhite I can wait for you. Yes, can you believe that???

Comment: @アレックス Thank you for clarifying. We encourage people to use only one account per question on Stack Exchange, as it makes it easier to verify who asked the question and determine what needs to be answered. The way you phrased your comment, it could have been read as if you were a separate user reading between the lines of the person who asked the question.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister that doesn't matter, you better answer the question

Answer (score 1):

It takes up space on your server, uses up some of your bandwidth, and increases server latency.

In that sense it is not beneficial to your server.

However, it may promote your domain through more widespread use of it.

Comment: the question doesn't ask how it impacts the domain and especially server in general. It asks "in terms of SEO". And nothing else

Comment: @アレックス The question doesn't actually mention "SEO"?

Comment: @MrWhite are you asking or making a statement?

Comment: @アレックス Well, both. The question does not actually mention "SEO". Yet, you are seemingly quoting a phrase from the question stating that it does? And this answer does touch on the SEO aspect anyway.

Comment: @MrWhite Where are we - on the website about SEO or about movies?

Comment: @アレックス Webmasters SE is not just about SEO. If you have a question specifically about SEO then you should at the very least use the `seo` tag and preferably mention something about SEO (ranking, search engines) in the question.

Comment: @MrWhite I'm telling you now: the question is about SEO